# Encountering 'The Current Platform is Unsupported' Error While Installing Clangd via Mason on ARM Server

Tags: neovim, clangd

When attempting to install a C++ LSP on an ARM server, I encountered the error mentioned above. Then, I found that Clangd from Mason does not support ARM servers. How can I resolve this issue? Alternatively, are there any other recommended C++ LSP options available in Mason?

Answer (score 1):

While editors / editor plugins may offer mechanisms for automatically installing language servers as a convenience, you can generally fall back to downloading the server manually and pointing your editor at it.

In the case of clangd, it's part of the LLVM project, and clangd binaries are included in the LLVM packages available on the LLVM project's releases page (e.g. [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-17.0.6) for the latest version, 17.0.6), and there are packages available for a variety of operating systems and architectures (e.g. `clang+llvm-17.0.6-aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz` is a Linux ARM package).

I'm not familiar with Mason specifically, but presumably it (or neovim itself) has an option to specify the path of the language server binary to use (which would be at `bin/clangd` in the directory where the package above is extracted).